# Jquery capturing multiple form events in one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following to capture the checkbox check event of form with id="form1":

```
$('#form1 :checkbox').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert($this.val());
}
```

I now have another form (id="form2") with checkboxes for which I need to handle events.  Is there any way to combine both forms into a single line and have the `alert` still pop up the correct value? i.e. something like

```
$('#form1 OR #form2 :checkbox').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert($this.val());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca do it using a [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like this:

```
$('#form1 :checkbox, #form2 :checkbox').click(function() {
```

Or [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), to make it a bit shorter, like this:

```
$('#form1, #form2').find(':checkbox').click(function() {
```

Comment: looks like you answered first (by a few seconds) so I'll accept your answer.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form1, #form2').find('input:checkbox').click(function() { ... });
```

---

edit: this is a side note, but use 'input:checkbox' instead of ':checkbox'. This allows the selector engine to only filter *input* tags that are checkboxes, rather than *all* tags that are checkboxes, and is therefore a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to combine both forms
>   into a single line and have the alert
>   still pop up the correct value?

Yes:

#### Using a comma

```
$('#form1 :checkbox, #form2 :checkbox').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert($this.val());
};
```

#### Or Using `add` method

```
$('#form1 :checkbox').add('#form2 :checkbox').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert($this.val());
};
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/add/